# Ionic NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription, NSCameraUsageDescription, NSMicrophoneUsageDescription

Tags: ionic-framework

How do I handle adding these descriptions in Ionic in a way that I can check into the repo and will be included automatically on build?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try putting something like this in your `/hooks/after_prepare` directory with e.g. filename `030_add_ios_usage_descriptions.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

PLIST=platforms/ios/*/*-Info.plist

cat << EOF |
Delete :NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription
Add :NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription string "For meal photos"
Delete :NSCameraUsageDescription
Add :NSCameraUsageDescription string "For meal photos"
Delete :NSMicrophoneUsageDescription
Add :NSMicrophoneUsageDescription string "For voice notes"
EOF
while read line
do
  /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "$line" $PLIST
done

true
```

You may also need to run `chmod +x` on the file.

Comment: Thanks, this worked after I did a chmod +x on the script file.